# Rails console large hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I am creating a large hash in an editor, then instantiating it in the rails console like so:

```
my_hash = {} #large hash
```

with copy and paste. I'm doing this so I can set some data in the db.  However, there seems to be some sort of buffer limit.  Anything over a certain size fails, the hash does not get created.  Is there a setting I can change to get around this? Thanks

Comment: If you are handling such large code, you shouldn't be using a console. Write it in a file and let Ruby read it.

Comment: I've pasted some really large arrays and hashes in console, I've never run into a limit.  Could the structure be incorrect?  And, you can use new lines, may help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better way to populate your database is with `seeds.rb` . It's in the /db folder of your rails project `/your_project/db/seeds.rb`

You can make your hash in there

```
my_hash{put: 'your', data: 'here'}

YourClass.create(my_hash)
```

Now to run seeds.rb , go to console and run `rake db:seed`. If you are using bulder in your project you need to run it like this `bundle exec rake db:seed`

Don't run seeds.rb more than once with the same data in it though, or you'll end up with duplicate data.